# Migrate apk testing from fabric to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Currently, Fabric is supporting uploading APK to their servers and invite testers using their email to download the application.

Now, what will happen after google kill fabric mid-2019, will we be able to upload our testing apk somewhere and inv users to test it?

If it already exists on firebase please share where to do that and if not, and there's another tool to do so let us know.

Comment: For a short time period, you can use https://www.diawi.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

What you're describing is a product called Crashlytics Beta.

From the [Fabric roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap):

> **MID 2019**
>
> Start using the next generation of Crashlytics Beta
>
> Get valuable feedback on pre-release iOS and Android apps by using Firebase App Distribution, the new version of Crashlytics Beta, to distribute beta builds to your team.

Keep an eye out for an update on the status of Firebase App Distribution and the Fabric roadmap in the [What's new in Firebase](https://events.google.com/io/schedule/events/8046ba76-9592-43e7-b63a-96ed9c1ce320) session at I/O.

Comment: thanks, Frank for your answer I already have checked this and I noticed all of the fabric data has been moved to firebase but I cannot find the API or section to upload apk using firebase.

Comment: The functionality to share a beta version of your app with specific users is part of Crashlytics Beta, which isn't available under the Firebase umbrella yet.

Comment: ah great thanks, I will keep an eye for the upcoming events and updates, do you know any tool you could suggest to do something similar?  I have searched for too long about a tool to upload apk with API and I couldn't find any not even google play store console as beta or alpha because as far as I know, google play store API is only to update the current project and it doesn't create a new project and upload first apk to it

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for off-site resources are off topic on Stack Overflow and will lead to your question being closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can request early access to Beta in Firebase, called App Distribution.
Current progress and registration is here: https://get.fabric.io/roadmap